# PFInstallation Error When Trying Save

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

Im trying to update a field in a PFInstallation object. My iOS Code is:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        installation[@"userId"] = @"none";

        [installation saveEventually:^(BOOL suceeded, NSError *error){

            if (suceeded) {

                [PFUser logOutInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSError *error){

                    if (!error) {

                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    }


                }];

            }

            else{

                NSLog(@"Error Logging Out: %@", error);
            }

         }];
```

It use to work fine before, but for some reason using Parse Server I get the following error:

[Error]: at least one ID field (deviceToken, installationId) must be specified in this operation (Code: 135, Version: 1.12.0)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you logged in before trying that? This looks like you have not registered your user, so you don't have a device token, and therefore can't run those functions properly

Comment: Yeah the user is logged in, I'm actually trying to run this code first before I log the user out. In the completion block of saving the PFInstallation I then logout the user if the save succeeded, but I'm getting this error in the block instead.